# Drupal 7 views exposed filter not working

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I made a view with the view UI in drupal then I exported the code and created a custom module implementing hook_views_default_views() and making some changes. The view works fine and I have a lot of filters. All work except 1, a type: grouped filter

```
    $handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['id'] = 'field_FIELDNAME_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_FIELDNAME';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['field'] = 'field_FIELDNAME_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_FIELDNAME_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['expose']['label'] = 'Field Label';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_FIELDNAME_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_FIELDNAME_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
    2 => '2',
    1 => 0,
    3 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['is_grouped'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['group_info']['label'] = 'Field Label';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['group_info']['identifier'] = 'field_FIELDNAME_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['group_info']['group_items'] = array(
    1 => array(
        'title' => 'Test',
        'operator' => 'or',
        'value' => array(
            2630 => '2630',
            2631 => '2631',
        ),
    ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'VOCABULARY_NAME';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['hierarchy'] = 1;
```

The view works and has no errors or notices, all filters display and work fine except this one.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours .. I found that it was a view issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2224601

The solution is to Just check allow multiple selections, save view, and then un-check multiple selections this will put this line into the view:

```
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_FIELDNAME_tid']['expose']['multiple'] = TRUE;
```